# E_ALL | E_COMPILE_ERROR does not show fatal error (cant redeclare function)

Tags: php, error-handling, compiler-errors

For this error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sc_trace_page() (previously declared [...yadayada]

I tried all these:

```
error_reporting('E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE'); 
error_reporting('E_ALL | E_COMPILE_ERROR');
error_reporting('E_COMPILE_ERROR |E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR|E_PARSE');
error_reporting(32767);
```

Only 32767 shows the error.  Even in the error_log.  Both WAMP and a name-brand shared hosting.  Seems pretty not smart that I could have E_ALL and not have it show me...'ALL' the errors.  But, of course, I dont want notices.

So, what am I failing to understand and how can I acheive the correct error reporting?

Comment: it was my use of quotes... blah.  Dont quote what you put in error_reporting(); Only the 32767 worked because it was the only valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) at least in your WAMP? These are constants, not strings so.. without quotes!

You also can declare a function only if it hasn;t been declared previously

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
    function my_function(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`error_reporting(32767);` is nothing but a decimal representation of `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Notice that there is no quotes around these values as they are predefined error constants.

You want to find out what combination of error_reporting constants trap the desired reporting that you are looking for.

Try mixing and matching the error constants provided in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) or if you want to continue the decimal representation, [try this link](http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard)